# React Admin | Uncaught Error: Missing history prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-admin

I am trying to implement react-admin in my project however upon render I get this message

```
Uncaught Error: Missing history prop. When integrating react-admin inside an existing redux Provider, you must provide the same 'history' prop to the <Admin> as the one used to bootstrap your routerMiddleware. React-admin uses this history for its own ConnectedRouter.
```

There is very little to be found about this issue and I'm not entirely sure how to go about setting the history. I've tried importing createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory' but then I get this error

```
Uncaught Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"
```

Is there a way to get this rendering properly? And if so, what would be the proper way to go about configuring the Admin Component's history?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { reducer } from './redux/reducer';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome') ?
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : compose,
  ),
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**AdminPage.js**

```
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:3000');

const AdminPage = () => {

  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="services" />
    </Admin>
  )
}

export default AdminPage;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AdminPage from './components/AdminPage';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/manage' component={ AdminPage } />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write a reducer in this case is documented at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html#using-an-existing-redux-provider.

But from what I see, you don't need one. You just added the thunk middleware, which is useless in react-admin as it already handles sagas.

Comment: I previously configured thunk before considering implementing react-admin...but thank you I will explore the documentation provided